# How do I create an action when all monsters are dead in maplestory?

Tags: java, game-engine

Lets make some code Examples to help you understand me and then I'll write my question in letters, hope you will help me to solve it :).

Btw, I'm programming an maplestory source that is based on java for who that know about the game source codes.

*For the peoples who know about maplestory source code, I want to create an action that happens when all monsters on the map are dead, the first action is the Summon action its summoning the mobs. So `action2()` it's the Action that happens when `mobCount` method is 0.

Okay then I got this code for example:

```
private int number;
public void action1() {
    this.number = 1;
    action2();//it calls action2.
}

public void action2() {
}
```

Now I need `action2()` to start when numb for example = 0. I already got the get method and the set method and all of that, but when I run `action1()` Number must stay 1. It has to call `action2()` because then no one else call it, but I need `action2()` to action only when number = 0. I'll create the action that set number back to 0 later, but for now I need to make it freeze and wait until number change back to 0 or else the action will not run and when number will be equals 0 then `action2()` will run the action.

I hope I explained myself clear enough to make you guys know what I mean.

Comment: Actions don't just trigger themselves. Check out the observer (callback/listener) pattern.

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis do you have any explains or somthing that i can read for understanding better?

Comment: I put keywords in my comment specifically so that you could look them up yourself.

Comment: You should also consider reading up on the producer/consumer pattern

Comment: I hate to say it but your question is still a mess.  Have you programmed in Java before? What sort of programs did you write in the past?

Comment: You haven't breath deep, didn't you?

Comment: This fine, Im just sorry of my bad english and my mess brain =/ someone of you guys can give me an example in code?

Comment: Well i did program before, but i never heared on a when action , Like the action will wait until somthing will happend and just after that respond so i came here and ask you guys how can i do it.

Comment: My best advice is to put this "maple task" aside and learn a little bit more about Java-Core before continuing it. You've got some nice keywords to start with :)

Comment: You were told about property change listeners. The easy solution was also given: call the method from the setter. Anything more complex is going to lead to even more confusion, hence the advice to take a step back and get some better grounding before programming yourself into a corner.

Comment: Dave Newton i tooked you'r advice, and im also agree with you , but i really have to know if somthing like that is possible and if it is how it works, so i'll be really glad if you will give me an example for my question =]

Comment: What are you even trying to do? AFAIK, maplestory involves no programming or custom actions, are you trying to make a training bot or something? (which is definitely against their ToS)

Comment: Lol nope, it isn't a BOT or somthing iLegal , only programming a MapleStory Source.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to have a 'flag' to let action1() know if it can activate action2().

First off, I'd recommend you use a boolean (unless you need an integer for a specific reason) And if you want action2 to execute only when number==0, then I'd recommend this:

```
private int number;
public void action1() {
    if(this.number == 0){
        this.number = 1;
        action2();//it calls action2.
    }
}
```

If that's not the answer, then please expand on what you're trying to accomplish and I can give you a more accurate answer.

Edit:
The correct answer is given in the comments

Comment: Yea it calls action2 but , action2 is running amideatly after he call it, i can use a timer or somthing i do know how to create a timer but i dont want to use atimer i want the action to automaticly know when number equals 0 and automaticly run. and i dont want to to run i want it to wait until number will change back to 0 again. so it didnt solve my question.

Comment: Very sorry for the misunderstanding, You could have a while loop that will wait for 1,000ms, or put an integer in the class that is basically 'millisecs_for_action'. Set it to the millisecs that you want to action (so 1000 + the current millisecs) and every time you pass it in the main loop, check if the current millisecs is greater than the time you're suppose to wait for.

Comment: Does that help at all?

Comment: Yea i tought about making atimer but in my problem it isn't the correct answer because If i tell action2 to run in like 3 seconds after action1() maybe number still =1 so the effect still be the same. i need it to run amiddetly when number changed to 0.

Comment: So it doesn't matter the time difference, You want the action2 to listen to the number. When it hits 0, no matter what changed it, action2 will run when it changes to 0.

In that case I would recommend listening to Dave Newton, and look up property change listeners. I don't know too much about it myself, but I trust this website: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

Comment: You're correct that what i meant :) and thanks alot , it helped me alot!